# array 2d Multidimensional and insert distance on arraymultidemensional array

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, arraylist

I want to calculate the distance in N cities and take probability inter-city.

I cannot get insertion on a multidimensional array working in PHP.

Can anyone you help me with inserting distances into a 2d array?

```
class jarak2d extends addLat{

    var $simpanjarak;

    public function __construct() {   
        $this->simpanjarak=array_values(array(array()));
     }

    public function simpanbobot($simpanjarak) {
        $a = $this->simpanjarak = $simpanjarak;
        if (!empty($a));
        {
            $this->addbaru=$a;
         }
         return $this->addbaru;
    }   

    public function gethasiljarak()
    {
        return $this->addbaru;
    }         
}

class addLat {
    var $simpan;
    var $simpanlat;

   var $simpanlng;
    var $lata;
    var $long;
    var $simpanjarak;
    var $bobot;
    var $addbaru;

    public function __construct() {
        $this->lata = array();
        $this->long = array();
        $this->simpan = array();
        $this->lat = array();
        $this->lng = array();

        $this->simpanjarak = array();
    }

    public function addKota($addLat) {
        $this->simpan = $addLat;
        $address = $this->simpan;

        $coordinates = file_get_contents('http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' . urlencode($address) . '&sensor=true');
        $coordinates = json_decode($coordinates);
        echo 'Latitude:' . $coordinates->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;
        echo "<br \>";
        echo 'Longitude:' . $coordinates->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;
        echo ' <br \> Address ' . $address . '<br \>';
        echo "<br \>";
        $lat = $coordinates->results[0]->geometry->location->lat;

        $lng = $coordinates->results[0]->geometry->location->lng;

        $a = $this->lata = $lat;
        $b = $a;
        $this->lata = $b;

        $c = $this->long = $lng;
        $d = $c;
        $this->long = $d;

        //      echo "<br \> Latitude " . $this->lata . "<br \>";
    }

    public function insertLat($lata) {
        $this->lata = lata;
    }

    public function insertLong($long) {
        $this->long = long;
    }

    public function getLat() {
        //echo $this->lata;
        return $this->lata;
    }

    public function getLong() {
        //echo $this->long;
        return $this->long;
    }

    public function addJarak($berangkat, $tujuankota) {

        $berangkat = urlencode($berangkat);
        $tujuankota = urlencode($tujuankota);

        $data = file_get_contents("http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/distancematrix/json?origins=$berangkat&destinations=$tujuankota&language=en-EN&sensor=false");
        $data = json_decode($data);

        //$waktu = 0;
        $jarak = 0;

        foreach ($data->rows[0]->elements as $road) {
            $jarak += $road->distance->value;
            $jarak = $jarak / 1000;
        }

        echo "Berangkat: " . $data->origin_addresses[0];
        echo "<br \>";
        echo "Tujuan : " . $data->destination_addresses[0];

        echo "<br \>";
        echo "Jarak: " . $jarak . " KM";
        echo "<br \>";
        echo "<br \>";

        $a = $this->simpanjarak = $jarak;
        echo $a;
        return $a;
    }

    public function getJarak() {
        return $this->simpanjarak;
    }                    
}

    $addLat = new addLat();

    $test = 'Jakarta';
    $test1 = 'Brebes';
    $test2='Pekalongan';
    $test3 ='Semarang';

    /*jarak */
    $berangkat = $test;
    $tujuankota = $test1;
    $addLat->addJarak($berangkat, $tujuankota);
    $hasil1 = array('Kota Berangkat' => $berangkat, 'Kota Tujuan' => $tujuankota, 'Jarak' => $addLat->getJarak() . ' KM');

    $hasiljarak = array (array($addLat->getJarak())) ;

    $bobot[] = $hasil1;

    //$simpanjarak  = $hasiljarak;

    $berangkat = $test1;
    $tujuankota = $test2;
    $addLat->addJarak($berangkat, $tujuankota);

    $hasil2 = array('Kota Berangkat' => $berangkat, 'Kota Tujuan' => $tujuankota, 'Jarak' => $addLat->getJarak() . ' KM');

    $hasiljarak1 = array(
        array($addLat->getJarak()),
        ($addLat->getJarak()),
        array($addLat->getJarak())
    );

    $bobot[] = $hasil2;

    $simpanjarak[]=$hasiljarak1;
    $simpanjarak[]=$hasiljarak;

    $add = new addJarak();
    $add->setNilai($bobot);
    echo "<br \>  <br \> ArrayList Jarak Antar Kota / KM<pre>" . print_r($add->getNilai(), true) . "</pre> <br />";

    $jarakd2= new jarak2d();

    $jarakd2->simpanbobot($simpanjarak);

    $jarakd2->simpanbobot($simpanjarak);
    echo "<pre>" .print_r($jarakd2->gethasiljarak(),true ). "</pre>";

    echo $hasiljarak[0][0] . $hasiljarak[1][0][0];
```

Comment: Welcome. Can you give us a small section of code which shows your problem?

Comment: Looks like your missing `array` down near where you assign `$hasiljarak` is that the 2d array your asking about? You really should specify what your trying to do and where and how your attempt is failing

Comment: $hasiljarak to get a value distance inter city , like city A and city B 70 miles @Terminus 
i hope you can helpe to show on array like 
    A    B   C 
A  0   10  25
B 10C

Comment: You need to find a calculation that will calculate the distance between 2 lat - long coordinates. Just search online for it or maybe even in a library.

Comment: @terminus - thank you i after fonded it to my question